# Why is this code not being shown on the terminal?

Tags: python

I wrote a game with a way for the player to repeat the game, and it is simply not being shown on the terminal

```
def game():

    secret_number = 9
    guess_count = 0
    guess_limit = 3

    while guess_count < 3:
        guess_count += 1
        guess = int(input('Guess: '))
        if guess == secret_number:
            print('You got it!')

    run_again = input('do you want to play again? Y/N: ')
    if run_again == 'Y':
        game()
    else:
        print('Bye')
        exit()
```

Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Did you call the `game()` function or did you just define it and actually forgot to call it?

Comment: Aside: Don't use recursion as a substitute for looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're making a mistake common among new programmers, looking at the function definition as a sort of label you can 'go to'. That's not how it works though, a function is a sealed off bit of code that you can call when its name is known (it is "in scope", as a programmer would say).

Your code defines the function, but only calls it from within itself, there is no call outside the function that can get it started.

Also, every time a function is called, this takes up some resources, and once a function reaches the end of its body, or a `return` statement, those resources are freed up and a value (or `None`) returned to wherever the function was called from. You call `game()` every time the player wants to play again and that could go on indefinitely, eating up some resources every time. You should instead just use a loop, like a `while`.

Changing those two things:

```
def game():
    while True:
        secret_number = 9
        guess_count = 0
        guess_limit = 3

        while guess_count < 3:
            guess_count += 1
            guess = int(input('Guess: '))
            if guess == secret_number:
                print('You got it!')

        run_again = input('do you want to play again? Y/N: ')
        if run_again != 'Y':
            print('Bye')
            # instead of exit() to terminate the script, just end the function
           return
        # if the code gets here, the `while True` will cause it to repeat
    # this point will never be reached, either while loops, or the function returns

# calling the function here, to get it to actually execute
game()
```

Comment: This worked! Also thanks for the advice

Comment: It is worth learning about the `if __name__ == __main__` idiom which is generally how python programmers distinguish between scripts (made to run like your game) vs modules (made to be called by another python program). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do